# TeamCity server in a Linux container, but Build Agent in a Windows container

Tags: docker, containers, dockerfile, teamcity, docker-for-windows

Is it possible to run a TeamCity server instance in a Linux container, and then run a Build Agent in a Windows container and have it connect?

Comment: Welcome to SO! What have you tried so far?

Comment: @Shane I have created a Linux teamcity server but then switch to windows container to run a build agent but it doens't seem to connect even though I believe I'm using the right URL. I tried the same URL back in Linux containers and was able to get a linux build agent to connect, but I need a windows build agent.

Answer (score 0):

The TeamCity Server just the central server, where Agents push the results. 
The TC Server is responsible for to add to queue, send a task to Agent, wait, collect the result.

The Agent is responsible for executing Task, send the result to the server.

doesn't matter, where was run TC or Agent, important point is that if your configuration needs the Windows server then it can be run only Agent on the Windows.

conclusion.

1. The TC Server can be run as on Linux, as on Windows OS's
2. The TC Agent also can be run on Linux and OS, but:

   1. If your configuration using the Windows component's, then the `Configuration` will add restrict OS type in the `Agent Requirements`

If you have few configurations with few OS type's just run few Agents on the some OS's